# Animation toolbarBackground visibility not works

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationstack

I'm trying to set toolbarBackground visibile with animation, but it's happen immediatly.
Are there ways to make this with animation?

```
struct MyView: View {
    @State private var barHidden = true
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Button("action") {
                barHidden.toggle()
            }
            .animation(.easeInOut, value: barHidden)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                    Text("Title")
                }
            }
            .toolbarBackground(Color.red, for: .navigationBar)
            .toolbarBackground(barHidden ? .hidden : .visible, for: .navigationBar)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you'd need to use UIKit/AppKit to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is take advantage of the `safeAreaInsets` modifier to simulate the animation of the toolbar background. Here's what I've done:

1. Get the `safeArea` size using a `GeomtryReader`
2. Apply the `safeAreaInsets` modifier to the `NavigationStack` to place a View where the toolbar is supposed to be, which, in this case, will be `Rectangle`
3. Add an `overlay` to aforementioned `Rectangle` that will be our title

Here's the code:

```
struct MyView: View {
    @State private var barHidden = true
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            let safeArea = proxy.safeAreaInsets
            NavigationStack {
                Button("action") {
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                        barHidden.toggle()
                    }
                }
            }
            .safeAreaInset(edge: .top) {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(barHidden ? .clear : .red)
                    .overlay(alignment: .center) {
                        Text("Title")
                            /// Placed exactly where the default Title appears when using the toolbar modifier
                            .padding(.top, safeArea.top / 2)
                    }
                    /// The red area I was seeing with your oringinal code was 2 times the safe area .top
                    .frame(height: safeArea.top * 2)
                    .ignoresSafeArea(.container, edges: .top)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the result:

[image: Animated Toolbar Backgound]